# Windows authentication not working asp.net mvc showing null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, windows-authentication

Web.Config windows authentication showing null username

My WebConfig authentication is enable

**C# code**
I tried

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // showing null
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  // showing null
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;// showing null
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] // showing null
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] // showing null
```

Comment: Are you hosting this with IISExpress?  Have you turn off Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: yes hosted on IIS and Anonymous Authentication is off

Answer (score 1):

Have you entered like this is Web.Config

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I checked Project properties window.

Anonymous Authentication was set Enabled and Windows Authentication - to Disabled. I changed these values and it helped me.

[image]

Comment: To open Project Properties Window in VS 2019: select your project in Solution Explorer and press F4 or go to  View -> Properties Windows.